# Как найти код отправки комментария в группу ВК через Xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Пытаюсь найти форму комментариев, перепробовал много вариантов, но никак не дается. Буду очень благодарен всем, кто напишет как это правильно сделать.

Код формы:

```
<div id="reply_field-57846937_45465522" class="reply_field submit_post_field" onfocus="return Wall.showEditReply('-57846937_45465522', event);" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Написать комментарий" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
```

Примерно моего кода:

```
# ищем поле для ввода комментария
comment = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Написать комментарий')]")
comment.clear()
comment.send_keys(comment1)
time.sleep(7)
```

Comment: Вы ищите элемент по XPATH, так и вставляйте маршрут в XPATH, полностью скопируйте элемент "Копировать полную строку XPATH".

Comment: Спасибо большое! Действительно, не замечал в хроме ссылку скопировать XPATH. По этой команде не выдает ошибку, но теперь не может следующие выполнить (почистить форму, вставить текст и отправить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вот документация](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/first_script/), в ней много фишек и прочей полезной инфы. Там же есть ссылки на гит

Если используете `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "#")` - то вместо `"#"` вставляете полную строку XPATH.

Для заполнения формы ищите по уникальному атрибуту, например для блока:

```
<div id="reply_field-57846937_45465522" class="reply_field submit_post_field" onfocus="return Wall.showEditReply('-57846937_45465522', event);" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Написать комментарий" bis_skin_checked="1"></div>
```

уникальным будет например `aria-label="Написать комментарий"`, не знаю как в действительности, но как пример. Уникальный - значит значение для данного атрибута есть только у этого блока и больше нигде не повторяется. Для поиска, очистки и ввода:

```
# ищем поле для ввода комментария
comment = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[aria-label="Написать комментарий"]')
comment.clear()
comment.send_keys(comment1)
time.sleep(7)
```

Это как пример, поэкспериментируйте сами используя документацию, в ней все методы поиска и заполнения форм описаны

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ. Инструкцию изучу. По вашему примеру кстати также находит элемент, но очистить и отправить не может

Comment: Вы комментарий пытаетесь где оставить? Под конкретной записью или на стене?

Comment: Задача заходить в группы и оставлять под второй записью сверху (запись рандомная, везде разные)

Comment: Ну вот, проблема в том, что вы получаете N-е количество блоков с [aria-label="Написать комментарий"], попробуйте циклом перебрать и подогнать как вам нужно, либо открывать в каждой группе вторую запись и уже в ней проводить манипуляции. У вас не выполняется главное условие о котором я ранее писал: значение для атрибута должно быть уникальным и не должно повторяться в других блоках, в ином случае бот не поймет, что очищать, куда писать и т.п.

Comment: Благодарю. Сделал по другому, с более конкретными путями получилось. Сначала кликнул по посту и уже в отдельном окне комментарий вписался в форму. Видимо было слишком много элементов на странице